# Groovy Array of Strings

Tags: groovy

I know curly brackets are not used to initialize array in Groovy but I have noticed one peculiar thing.

Why groovy doesn't give compiler error when I initialize an array like this.

```
String emailAddress = "test@gmail.com";

String [] var = {emailAddress};

println var[0];
```

Output: com.test.examples.GroovyTest$_main_closure1@12e4860e

When I try to declare like this I get error:

```
String [] var = {"a","b"};
```

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do:

```
String [] var = {emailAddress};
```

That creates a `Closure` that returns a String `emailAddress`, and then crams that closure into a String array (by calling `toString()` on it), as that's what you told it to do ;-)

So `var` equals `['ConsoleScript0$_run_closure1@60fd82c1']` (or similar, depending on where you're running things)

When you do:

```
String [] var = {"a","b"};
```

The right-hand side is not a valid Closure, so the script fails to parse.

What you want is:

```
String[] var = ['a', 'b']
```

Or:

```
String[] var = [emailAddress]
```